# How much freedom do we have when working with sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $$a_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log(n)$$ and suppose we are to show it is Cauchy. (*Do not solve the exercise for me. Spoilers are not welcome.*) While there maybe are better methods, my question is the following: for $n \ge  m \ge N$, I end up with the expression as part of my calculation $$\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{k} + \log(\frac{m}{n})$$ Am I free to say that $m$ and $n$ "grows big together", in a sense, in order to get the desired proximity to $\log(1)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You cannot assume any relation between $m$ and $n$ other than $m,n > N$ for some $N$. In particular you could even chose $m = 2n$ and see the $\log(2)$ appear.

Comment: it is more "$m,n$ are free to grow independently", you cannot control "how much they grow", nor their difference.

Comment: @AlexR, yes, that is what I suspected. Damned be the difference between sufficiently big and infinity.

Comment: @AndrewThompson A slight hint would be to look at the integral representation of $\log(\frac mn)$ ;)

Comment: I would like to avoid anything integralrelated at all. I'll figure it out somehow, thanks for confirming my suspicions!

Comment: If you find a proof without integrals that would be very interesting to see.